# Enable Automatic Migrations in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a MVC application where I add new classes very often. As the classes are related to each other and the test data in the the tables already created are of no interest I prefer to go with AutomaticMigrations.

i use the following command to set the database to the initial state.

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

But the problem is that it doesn't work always. What could be the possible reasons that it goes wrong? I am not familiar with Code First Migrations.

The error is mostly thrown during the runtime stating the DbContext was changed. I make sure there are no dependencies in the existing tables with the dropped tables before enabling the Migrations. I also get an error that states

```
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

I am looking for general help on the topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For automatic migrations first you should set Database Initializer in your Database Context constructor.

```
public class YourDBContext: DbContext 
{        
    public YourDBContext(): base("ConnectionString") 
    {
         Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDBContext>());
    }
```

You can also create custom Database initializer implementing `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDBContext>` with overridden seed method to provide initial data.

Second you should enable automatic migrations using command in Package Manager Console `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Then using `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console will apply to database all the pending changes that you have made after last migration.

Update : 
Use `Verbose` with update database command to see what script is generated

```
Update-Database –Verbose
```

Comment: when i add parameters to SetInitializer it doesnt work.

Comment: I am sure you ahve `$InitialDatabase` migration in your migrations directory! correct!!

Comment: i dont have a table for Migrations in my database.. Just now i checked to find it isnt there..

Comment: Oh, and what about `$InitialDatabase' migration, can you find it under Migrations directory??

Comment: No.. Even that is missing.. But the code worked fine when i give the parameter as null

Comment: Yes it would not created under Migrations directory because you have run automatic migration. But if you didn't find it in database even, than where do you find it!

Comment: I only have two tables in my database. But none for the Migration

Comment: But i have done the same thing in another program, there i can find migration table and initial migration inside my Migration folder

Comment: i am afraid i will not be able to join a chat at this moment. I have restricted access..

Comment: Have you used -Verbose with Update -Database command. It will show you whole script generated for the migration. Because it is difficult to figure out the cause of error, without analyzing all migrations and in which order you ran it.

Comment: i never used -Verbose flag,

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SystemFamilies] (
    [SystemFamilyID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [FamilyName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max),
    [deleteFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SystemsCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SystemFamilies] PRIMARY KEY ([SystemFamilyID])
)`

Comment: That was from the update script from Verbose.. And yes this is my table.

Comment: So, that is your table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want general help, I think Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx) is fairly good for starters. They also have some good tutorials to get you started correctly from the beginning.

For your current issue, could you elaborate on the exact issue? The error message shows something you'll need to fix yourself and is not necessarily an issue with EF.

**Update**:

Modify the custom DbContext's constructor with following line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: I had a model class and program working properly before adding more classes. Now i deleted the classes that I added, but the code doesn't work anymore. i usually go for AutomaticMigrations and enable data loss to drop the database tables and create it again. but this time i am not successful that way.

Comment: The link you  have posted is the place where i got all the keywords for automatic migrations. But it doesn't have anything to set the database to its intiial state.

Comment: You mean this line of code I suppose:  Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);

Comment: Shoudl i add the line of code in the DbContext or the migrations ?

Comment: I have added code from the previous answer to get it right. But where to add the code is now being questioned. I could get it right by adding it in the Migrations but the code should be placed in the DbContext as the answerer says.

Comment: After a quick review, I noticed I added this line of code in the DbContext's constructor. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No. I added this line of code in DbContext constructor but doesnt work. `public SystemsContext() : base("SystemsContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SystemsContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SystemsContext>());
        } ` Is there something wrong in the way i add?

Comment: Oh. sorry. i have changed the parameter to null and it works..#

Comment: Updated answer. If this worked, don't forget to mark this one as answered.

Comment: Yes sure. But why doesnt it now work with the parameter if model changes?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` if you always want to recreate the db rather than targeting the initialdatabase migration. More on the topic on the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)
In your context's constructor, e.g

```
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
    {        
        public SchoolDBContext(): base("SchoolDBConnectionString") 
        {
         Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolDBContext>());
        }
```

Comment: Where does this line of code fit in ?  i try adding it in the global.asax but it throws errors.

Comment: I added it in the migrations. Still it worked. So what is the differnce when i add it in the configuration.cs in migrations and datacontext?

Comment: `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations. ` I get this error when i added it in my `DbContext`

Comment: run the command: Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations, and then run the update-database command

Comment: `There is already an object named 'SystemFamilies' in the database` I get this error trying to do that.

Comment: since you dont need the data and im guessing this is on your local machine, i suggest you manually drop the db if you can

Comment: Yes this is on  my local machine. But i am not just looking for a workaround for the curretn situation, but also when it arises in a different situation. That time I could save a question in SO